# Do refresh tokens of Googledrive app expire?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Do refresh tokens that we get when we authorize the googledrive app expire, or can we use the same refresh token for years? If they expire, then how can we handle that situation with php?

Answer (score 4):

Refresh tokens do not expire but users can revoke them anytime. To handle that scenario your application should redirect the user back to the grant access page and request a new refresh token.

Check the PHP code at https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials#retrieve_oauth_20_credentials for an example showing how to handle the OAuth flow and build the authorization url when needed.